# In GmailAPI, how to retrieve messages that are new in the Inbox

Tags: gmail-api

I am using
 List unreadMsgs =
                GmailApi.ListMessages(myGmailService, "me", "in:unread");
as per google's example, but this brings in 1000's of messages, including ones that are archived, and no more in inbox

How can I limit my criteria to inbox?

Comment: try "is:unread" "in:" is usually used for folders reference - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could alter the query to just list messages that has the `INBOX`-label and are unread.

```
List unreadMsgs = GmailApi.ListMessages(myGmailService, "me", "in:inbox AND is:unread");
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I'd only point out that AND is assumed with Gmail search queries and does not need to be explicitly included. OP should take a look at Advanced Gmail Search article for better understanding of search query format: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en